# Using Task.Delay within Task.Run

Tags: c#, async-await, windows-services, topshelf

I have a Windows Service that monitors my application by running a couple of tests every second. A bug report has been submitted that said that the service stoppes running after a while, and I'm trying to figure out why.

I suspect that the code below is the culprit, but I have trouble understanding exactly how it works. The ContinueWith statement has recently been commented out, but I dont know if it is needed

```
private Task CreateTask(Action action)
{
    var ct = _cts.Token;
    return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            while (true)
            {
                sw.Restart();
                action();

                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    _logger.Debug("Cancellation requested");
                    break;
                }

                var wait = _settings.loopStepFrequency - sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                if (wait <= 0) // No need to delay
                    continue;

                // If ContinueWith is needed wrap this in an ugly try/catch 
                // handling the exception
                await Task.Delay(
                    (int)(_settings.loopStepFrequency - sw.ElapsedMilliseconds),
                    ct); //.ContinueWith(tsk => { }, ct);
            }

            _logger.Debug("Task was cancelled");
        }, _cts.Token);
}
```

Are there any obvious problems with this code?

Comment: You might want to use an `System.Timers.Timer` to schedule the tests. If your `_cts` is cancelled while in `Task.Delay` you will get an exception, so you might need to use a try-catch for that.

Comment: **Why** do you think this is related to the service stopping issue?

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any obvious problems with this code?

The one that jumps out to me is the calculation for the number of milliseconds to delay. Specifically, there's no floor. If `action()` takes an unusually long time, then the task could fail in a possibly unexpected way.

There are several ways for the task to complete in either a cancelled or failed state, or it can delay forever:

1. The task can be cancelled before the delegate begins, due to the cancellation token passed to `Task.Run`.
2. The task can be cancelled by the `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` call.
3. The task can complete successfully after being cancelled, due to the `IsCancellationRequested` logic.
4. The task can be cancelled by the cancellation token passed to `Task.Delay`.
5. The task may fail with an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if `_settings.loopStepFrequency - sw.ElapsedMilliseconds` is less than `-1`. This is probably a bug.
6. The task may delay indefinitely (until cancelled) if `_settings.loopStepFrequency - sw.ElapsedMilliseconds` happens to be exactly `-1`. This is probably a bug.

To fix this code, I recommend two things:

1. The code is probably intending to do `await Task.Delay((int) wait, ct);` instead of `await Task.Delay((int)(_settings.loopStepFrequency - sw.ElapsedMilliseconds), ct);`. This will remove the last two conditions above.
2. Choose one method of cancellation. The standard pattern to express cancellation is via `OperationCanceledExcpetion`; this is the pattern used by `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` and by `Task.Delay`. The `IsCancellationRequested` check is using a different pattern; it will successfully complete the task on cancellation, instead of cancelling it.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! I have a couple of questions: If action() takes an unusual long time, then 'var wait' will become negative and the delay wont happen?

Comment: Regarding point 5: This will only happen if "var wait" is set to 1 or more, and then it takes 2ms to get to the Delay statement?

Comment: @Q-bertsuit: Yes and yes.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many problems with this code, that makes more sense to rewrite it than attempt to fix it. Here is a possible way to rewrite this method, with some (possibly superfluous) argument validation added:

```
private Task CreateTask(Action action)
{
    if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));
    var ct = _cts.Token;
    var delayMsec = _settings.loopStepFrequency;
    if (delayMsec <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("loopStepFrequency");
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var delayTask = Task.Delay(delayMsec, ct);
            action();
            await delayTask;
        }
    }, ct);
}
```

The responsibility for logging a possible exception/cancellation belongs now to the caller of the method, that (hopefully) awaits the created task.

```
var task = CreateTask(TheAction);
try
{
    await task; // If the caller is async
    //task.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // If the caller is sync
    _logger.Info("The task completed successfully");
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    _logger.Info("The task was canceled");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.Error("The task failed", ex);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Much appreciated